# Calculating differential of inverse function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

[image: This is the problem and my work on it.] trying to find $(f'^{-1})(a)$ and am getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Try writing it out carefully instead of a bunch of scattered barely legible scribblings. You may find where you've got lost. If you do it by putting it into mathjax, you can also post it, and maybe get some help instead of being ignored because nobody wants to try and interpret this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to find the value of the inverse of the derivative at a single point, so that makes things easier.  You are right to start with the canonical formula $$(f')^{-1}(a)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))}$$ So let's compute the ingredients.  Now, $f(x)=\frac{3}{x+2}$, correct?  So, its derivative is $f'(x)=-\frac{3}{(x+2)^{2}}$.  Next, set up the equation $$a=\frac{3}{x+2}$$ Solve for $x$ in terms of $a$, and this will give us $f^{-1}(a)$: $$a(x+2)=3$$ $$ax=3-2a$$ $$x=\frac{3-2a}{a}=\frac{3}{a}-2$$ so $$f^{-1}(a)=\frac{3}{a}-2$$ Thus, $$f'(f^{-1}(a))=-\frac{3}{(\frac{3}{a}-2+2)^{2}}=-\frac{3}{(\frac{3}{a})^{2}}=-\frac{3}{\frac{9}{a^{2}}}=-\frac{a^{2}}{3}$$ Thus, $$(f')^{-1}(a)=-\frac{3}{a^{2}}$$